# Need Help AOSP Build Error for snapdragon 8974

Tags: android, build, android-source

I'm trying to build Android 5.0 source code from code-aurora for snapdragon 8074. Encountered the following error:

```
target SharedLib: libandroid_runtime (out/target/product/msm8974/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_runtime.so)
frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Paint.cpp:809: error: undefined reference to 'android::uirenderer::Blur::convertRadiusToSigma(float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/target/product/msm8974/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/LINKED/libandroid_runtime.so] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (06:19:52 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

And I had downloaded the source code mentioned for the snapdragon8074.
I ran the following commands to build

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch msm8974-userdebug
$ make
```

Can anyone kindly help with the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Is this for the 8074, or the 8974? "...processors include the following part numbers: 8074, 8274, 8674 and 8974": qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/processors/800 Your prose and commandlines differ. –  ahcox 6 mins ago

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

This is for 8074, Intrinsyc DevKit. But i had to build using. 

<$lunch msm8974-userdebug>
Since there is no specific lunch for **8074**.
Thanks @ahcox

Comment: Hi @ahcox, can you pleas suggest any solution to this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry @Harish, I was only here because SO asked me to help moderate an edit of your question that changed all the SOC designations from msm8074 to msm8974. I have no help to offer on the meat of your question :'(.

Comment: That's alright @ahcox thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `USE_OPENGL_RENDERER := true` to your `BoardConfig.mk` (in your case this file is under `device/qcom/msm8974`).
This is so because on modern builds of Android hardware accelerated graphics are pretty much mandatory. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79116).

As a side note, for [Code Aurora](https://www.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/WebHome) you should be using *choosecombo* instead of *lunch* (in your case `choosecombo 1 msm8974 2`).

Comment: Hi @Filipe,
Thanks for the reply. 
I changed made the changes you suggested in the BoardConfig.mk file which was under device/qcom/msm8974. And tried building it again with the 
    $make -j4 command. 
But I encountered the same error.
Now I will "make clean" and I will try to build using 
"choosecombo 1 msm8974 2" 
and I'll update the outcome.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried the lunch choosecombo 1 msm8974 2. But the out put message was "Invalid lunch combo: choosecombo". And when I checked all the available options using "lunch", I had only 3 options for MSM :
14. msm8974-userdebug
     15. msm8610-userdebug
     16. msm8226-userdebug  
So I'm building again using "lunch msm8974 user-debug" and with the changes in BoardConfig.mk. Please suggest me a solution. @filipeg

Comment: You should use choosecombo **instead** of lunch.

You should not use lunch, only `choosecombo 1 msm8974 2`

Comment: yes I realized after I initiated the build using lunch again...
All the .img files are generated except the system.img...
I'm going to build using choosecombo now...
Thanks @Filipe

Comment: Hi @Filipe, The build failed again with the same error, even after using the "choosecombo 1 msm8974 2"

Comment: I made the following changes to the paint.cpp file. added a header `29 #include "SkBlurMask.h" ... 810 SkScalar sigma = SkBlurMask::ConvertRadiusToSigma(radius); 811 //android::uirenderer::Blur::convertRadiusToSigma(radius);` The built finished successfully. After i flashed the binaries on the board. it did not boot at all. Booting stopped in 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: From what I see above you may be trying to build for the wrong chipset ( 8094 is not the same as 8974). Besides, you may also be missing specific drivers for your device, since code aurora may not provide them.

Comment: Hi @Filipe,
 The snapdragon 8074 and 8974 are almost similar except that the 8074 does not have a cellular modem. 
I've downloaded the source code for Kitkat, built it using `lunch msm8974-userdebug` and flashed it on the board  and it was running fine. 
No build error nor boot error, I guess it was a stable branch. It was a cake walk basically. I just had to execute commands. 
I'm new to this, So can you suggest me how should I approach?

Comment: If you can build but can't boot it could be a lack of drivers issue. I can't help you much there but you can find more thorough help in a specialized forum (such as xda-developers).